# white noise has flat power spectral density

Tags: matlab, fft

I am trying to prove that the white noise has constant power spectral density using matlab 
but the amplitude of the spectrum looks like random amplitude.

can anyone tell me why?

here is my code.

```
noise = randn(1,10000);
fft_noise=fft(noise);
plot(abs(fft_noise(1:5000)))
```

thanks.

Comment: Better on Signal processing or Mathematics forum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to average a bunch (law of large numbers) of FFTs of white noise to approach the average power spectral density.

Answer (score 3):

If you take the FFT of an independent set of random variables from the same distribution, then you'll get an independent set of random variables from the same distribution since the inverse Fourier transform is (more or less) the same as the Fourier transform. The point is that the expected value for each frequency is the same.

Comment: But note that the expected value of the magnitude (`abs`) is not the same as the magnitude of the expected value.

Answer (score 0):

you need to multiple the fft by the complex conjugate of the fft to show a flat PSD. i.e. change

```
fft_noise=fft(noise);
```

to

```
fft_noise=fft(noise).*conj(fft(noise));
```